# How could Godzilla sense Mechagodzilla?

Tags: monsterverse, godzilla-vs-kong

Madison encountered Mechagodzilla at the Apex facility, and says to Bernie:

> This is why Godzilla attacked the Apex facility. They're trying to replace him.

Mechagodzilla had never left the Apex facility before, so how could Godzilla have sensed it?

Comment: Something something, hollow earth, something something.

Comment: I assumed it was the "bio-acoustics" introduced in King of the Monsters.

Comment: *Midichlorians* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Godzilla isn't sensing Mechagodzilla, rather he's sensing Ghidorah's severed head, which is used by the pilot, Ren Serizawa, to telepathically link to and subsequently control Mechagodzilla.

Given that the skull is kept at the Apex facility, Godzilla would naturally head straight there, regardless of where Mechagodzilla is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it’s because of the eyeballs of Mechagodzilla, pulsating and emitting these strange sounds, like the ORCA, just a different frequency maybe. It would explain the distance Godzilla is able to detect it. In the previous film, Godzilla II: King of the Monsters, the ORCA emitting the frequency was able to affect titans around the globe.

We can see one eye at the ending of the facility destruction scene, with Godzilla wreaking havoc in the background while the eye pulsates and emits sound.
When Mechagodzilla is first seen in action, the scene ends with the eye again pulsating and emitting sounds, and Godzilla immediately changing course due to it.